# Is it possible to make a if statement look at 2 strings independently?

Tags: python

I don't know how exactly to word it so ill just explain,

```
elif careful != "yes"  "no":
```

How do i make the "yes" and "no" independent? When i put it in, it combines the "yes" and "no" together.

Output

```
'yesno'
```

I have tried using the '|' operator and the '&' operator

Here is the full code

```
 careful = input("Are you Careful?")

if careful == "yes":
    print("ok good, what is your age?")
    age = int(input("Your age?"))
    if age <= 13:
        print("sorry, paws is hiding")
    elif careful != "yes" "no":
        print("nonsense, say yes or no")
    else:
        print("Be careful! she nibbles, with no teeth")
else:
    print("you have to be careful!")
```

thanks

Comment: What does "independent" mean? What is the actual rule the code should implement?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
elif careful != "yes"  "no":
```

You can use

```
elif careful not in ("yes" , "no"):
```